# Adding to Pandas DataFrame using timestamps for index creates new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a script that reads data from a CSV and I want to append new data to the DF as it becomes available.  Unfortunately, when I do that, I always end up with new columns. The DF from the CSV looks like this when I print()

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

                      Temp    RH
Time                            
2021-05-17 11:08:34  51.08  77.9
2021-05-17 11:10:30  51.08  77.0
2021-05-17 11:10:35  50.72  71.9
2021-05-17 11:10:41  50.72  71.8
2021-05-17 11:12:19  50.72  71.6
...                    ...   ...
2021-05-24 17:13:57  55.22  70.2
2021-05-24 17:14:02  55.22  69.6
2021-05-24 17:14:08  55.22  68.1
2021-05-24 17:14:18  54.86  66.9
2021-05-24 17:14:29  54.68  69.3
```

I use the following to create a fake new df for testing

```
timeStamp = datetime.now()
timeStamp = timeStamp.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")
t = 51.06
h = 69.3
data = {'Temp': t, 'RH': h}
newDF = pd.DataFrame(data, index = pd.to_datetime([timeStamp]) )
print(newDF)
```

which gives me

```
                      Temp    RH
2021-05-24 17:28:32  51.06  69.3
```

Here is the output when I call append()

```
print(df.append([df, pd.DataFrame(newDF)], ignore_index = False))
                      Temp    RH   Temp    RH
2021-05-17 11:08:34  51.08  77.9    NaN   NaN
2021-05-17 11:10:30  51.08  77.0    NaN   NaN
2021-05-17 11:10:35  50.72  71.9    NaN   NaN
2021-05-17 11:10:41  50.72  71.8    NaN   NaN
2021-05-17 11:12:19  50.72  71.6    NaN   NaN
...                    ...   ...    ...   ...
2021-05-24 17:14:02  55.22  69.6    NaN   NaN
2021-05-24 17:14:08  55.22  68.1    NaN   NaN
2021-05-24 17:14:18  54.86  66.9    NaN   NaN
2021-05-24 17:14:29  54.68  69.3    NaN   NaN
2021-05-24 17:28:32    NaN   NaN  51.06  69.3

[223293 rows x 4 columns]
```

and concat()

```
df1 = pd.concat([df, newDF], ignore_index=False)
print(df1)
                      Temp    RH   Temp    RH
2021-05-17 11:08:34  51.08  77.9    NaN   NaN
2021-05-17 11:10:30  51.08  77.0    NaN   NaN
2021-05-17 11:10:35  50.72  71.9    NaN   NaN
2021-05-17 11:10:41  50.72  71.8    NaN   NaN
2021-05-17 11:12:19  50.72  71.6    NaN   NaN
...                    ...   ...    ...   ...
2021-05-24 17:14:02  55.22  69.6    NaN   NaN
2021-05-24 17:14:08  55.22  68.1    NaN   NaN
2021-05-24 17:14:18  54.86  66.9    NaN   NaN
2021-05-24 17:14:29  54.68  69.3    NaN   NaN
2021-05-24 17:28:32    NaN   NaN  51.06  69.3

[111647 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: set the axis explicitly https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Comment: axis=0 gives me the same as df1 = pd.concat([df, new_row], ignore_index=False)

Comment: are you positive the excel file headers don't have spaces? also, your index is named in from the excel file but not what you are appending. probably something obscure, but you may want to rename everything on both DFs and see what happens before append or concat

Comment: FML that was it.  I had manually added the headers and typed it with spaces after the commas. Now a simple df=df.append(newDF) works.  Thank you!

Comment: Devil's in the details! Good to know it was a simple fix.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
print(df.append([df, pd.DataFrame(newDF)], ignore_index = False))
```

Which I believe is keeping the columns of each unique dataframe, just call `append` on the original dataframe itself.

Try

```
df = df.append(newDF, ignore_index = False)
```

Comment: Sorry I accepted this answer too fast.  still gives me new columns.

Comment: Apologies, I see also that another user has posted a solution to the error.